# find replace name by source priority (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a file with many different poorly named mnemonics ("original Mnemonic"). I need to change the names of these poorly named mnemonics to a general name ("general mnemonic"). I believe I should do this with a dictionary, but I am not positive.

here is an example of the data (you can create a dataframe from the code below):

```
originalMnemonic = ['ABCGR1','ABCGR2','ABCGR3','ABCGR4','ABCRT1','ABCRT2','ABCRT3','ABCRT4']
generalMnemonic = ['GR','GR','GR','GR','RT','RT','RT','RT']
sourcePriority = [2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4]

curveDf = pd.DataFrame(
    {'originalMnemonic': originalMnemonic,
     'generalMnemonic': generalMnemonic,
     'sourcePriority': sourcePriority
    })
```

I have given each "original Mnemonic" a "general Mnemonic" name, I have also supplied a Source Priority.

How would I go about finding and replacing the names of the "original mnemonics" with the "general mnemonic" name. In order of source priority. (ie if source prioirty 1 is present, use 1. if 1 is not present use source priority 2.)

Here is an example of the file I would like to change:

```
curveName = ['ABCGR1', 'ABCGR2', 'ABCGR3', 'ABCGR4', 'ABCRT1', 'ABCRT2', 'ABCRT3', 'ABCRT4']

curveDesc = ['I only want this name to be GR','dont change name','dont change name','dont change name',
            'I only want this name to be RT','dont change name','dont change name','dont change name']

changeDf = pd.DataFrame(
    {'curveName': curveName,
     'curveDesc': curveDesc
    })
```

"curveName" should change to the "general Mnemonic" name from "curveDF" in source priority order.

Here is my desired output: (notice how ABCGR1 has changed to GR (it has source priority 2, and ABCRT1 has changed to RT (it has source priority 1)

```
originalMnemonic = ['GR','ABCGR2','ABCGR3','ABCGR4','RT','ABCRT2','ABCRT3','ABCRT4']
generalMnemonic = ['GR','GR','GR','GR','RT','RT','RT','RT']
sourcePriority = [2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4]

outputDf = pd.DataFrame(
    {'originalMnemonic': originalMnemonic,
     'generalMnemonic': generalMnemonic,
     'sourcePriority': sourcePriority
    })
outputDf
```

any help to get me on the right track is appreciated.

Comment: could you post your desired (resulting) data set?

Comment: i have added the desired output and changed some of the code to make more sense. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

source DF:

```
In [141]: curveDf
Out[141]:
  generalMnemonic originalMnemonic  sourcePriority
0              GR           ABCGR1               2
1              GR           ABCGR2               3
2              GR           ABCGR3               4
3              GR           ABCGR4               5
4              RT           ABCRT1               1
5              RT           ABCRT2               2
6              RT           ABCRT3               3
7              RT           ABCRT4               4
```

**Solution:**

```
In [142]: curveDf.loc[curveDf.groupby('generalMnemonic', as_index=0) \
                             .sourcePriority.idxmin(), \
                      'originalMnemonic'] =  curveDf.generalMnemonic

In [143]: curveDf
Out[143]:
  generalMnemonic originalMnemonic  sourcePriority
0              GR               GR               2
1              GR           ABCGR2               3
2              GR           ABCGR3               4
3              GR           ABCGR4               5
4              RT               RT               1
5              RT           ABCRT2               2
6              RT           ABCRT3               3
7              RT           ABCRT4               4
```

Explanation:

```
In [140]: curveDf.groupby('generalMnemonic', as_index=0).sourcePriority.idxmin()
Out[140]:
0    0
1    4
dtype: int64
```

**OLD answer:**

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
In [11]: curveDf.loc[curveDf.sourcePriority==1, 'originalMnemonic'] = curveDf.generalMnemonic

In [12]: curveDf
Out[12]:
  generalMnemonic originalMnemonic  sourcePriority
0              GR               GR               1
1              GR           ABCGR2               2
2              GR           ABCGR3               3
3              GR           ABCGR4               4
4              RT               RT               1
5              RT           ABCRT2               2
6              RT           ABCRT3               3
7              RT           ABCRT4               4
```

Comment: Thank you, that is the output I am looking for in my question, (but what happens if I dont have sourcePriority 1?, it will not move to 2, and then 3, and then 4). I think I need to rephrase my question.

Comment: @brandog, it would be much clearer if you would simply post your input and desired data sets with a short explanation...

Comment: Yes, I understand. I was just trying to simplify it and do it in small parts. My question is much more complex, I am trying to create a cross over name table by source priority, I enter .las files using the "lasio" package, then gather all the Mnemonics out of them, (i have competed this step). Then I need to take all the mnemonics which I have given a "general name" and find/replace the "original mnemonic" in the .las file. I have trouble simplifying the steps needed to do that. hence my poorly phrased question.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question.